# Is a metric space separable if every proper subspace is separable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, separable-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a non-empty metric space (i.e. $X \not = \emptyset$). As is well known, $X$ is called *[separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space)* if it contains a countable, dense subset.

If the non-empty metric space $(X,d)$ is separable, then a simple consequence is that every (non-empty) subspace $U \subseteq X$ is separable as well (see for example [the first property here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space#Properties)). I was wandering if the converse statement is true as well:

> Is a (non-empty) metric space separable if *every* subspace of it is separable?

I couldn't find anything about this question on the internet, please excuse if this is a somewhat "easy" or "trivial" question. Thanks for any help, advice, counterexample etc.!

**Edit:** As stated in the comments by Cameron Williams and David C. Ullrich, the question should have been formulated as follows:

> Is a (non-empty) metric space separable if *every **proper*** subspace of it is separable?

Comment: The whole space is its own subspace.

Comment: Of course, thanks for the hint! So the following statement would be true, I guess: "*A (non-empty) metric space is separable if and only if every of its subspaces is separable*"...or do we have to exclude the case $U = X$ somehow?

Comment: @ComplexFlo You don't have to, but the question is infinitely more interesting if you ask if it can be concluded that $X$ is separable if every proper subspace is separable.

Comment: Of course, as noted, the fact that $X$ is a subspace of itself makes the question as asks literally trivial. You meant to ask whether $X$ must be separable if every _proper_ subspace is separable. That's not trivial in the same sense, but still very easy: if $p\in X$ then $X\setminus\{p\}$ is a proper subspace of $X$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams/David C. Ullrich: Thanks for your correction, that's actually the case I'm interested in ;-) If you allow, let me get more concrete: I have a metric space $(X,d)$ and a proper(!) subspace $(U,d)$. I know that $U$ is separable if and only if a certain criterion is fulfilled. Now I'd like to show that this criterion is also necessary and sufficient for $X$ to be separable. Necessity is easy due to the mentioned subspace property of separability (see my original question). For sufficieny, I need that separability of every *proper* subspace implies that $X$ itself is separable...

Comment: Trivially, the separability of every proper subspace of $X$ implies that $X$ itself is separable. But how is that going to help you prove that your space $(X,d)$ is separable? It sounds like you don't know that *every* subspace is separable, all you know is that the particular subspace $(U,d)$ is separable.